# Irrationality Measure Multiplied by a Constant

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $\alpha$ be any real number, and let $\mu$ be the irrationality measure of $\alpha$. Does there exist a number $c > 0$ such that:
$$\left | \frac{p}{q} - \alpha \right | \geq \frac{c}{q^\mu}$$

for all nonzero integers $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Something like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k \cdot 3^k}$ might be a counterexample, though you'd have to prove that this has irrationality measure $3$ and not anything higher.